# Add hyperlink to share functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, share

I have this share function:

```
NSString *URLEncodedText = [someId stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *ourPath = [@"something://" stringByAppendingString:URLEncodedText];
NSString *textToShare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My message that I want to have this link %@", someId];

NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, ourPath];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is there a way to send the share as a Link and not show `ourPath` to the user?

This is the end result that I'm getting
something://xxxxxxx

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking if you can send a "Share" link to someone while suppressing the URL? If so, how do you expect the recipient to be able to access the content? Do you know of an example of a feature that works like what you want?

Comment: not supressing, but do it like this: [My message that I want to have this link](http://www.google.com)